# Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed file not recognized: File truncated

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I started working on my project again after a break of 4-5 days, and when I am trying to do `catkin_make`, i get the following error

```
Base path: /home/kashyap/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/build"
####
[ 28%] Built target media_files
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LaserScannerSignal
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AccessPoint
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PressureState
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PeriodicCmd
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryState
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_LaserTrajCmd
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_AccelerometerState
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryServer2
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PowerState
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetPeriodicCmd
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryState2
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_DashboardState
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_BatteryServer
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetLaserTrajCmd
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_PowerBoardState
[ 28%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 28%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 28%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 28%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 28%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 28%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 28%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 28%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 28%] Built target _pr2_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GPUStatus
[ 28%] Built target _ur_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetIO
[ 28%] Built target _ur_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ToolDataMsg
[ 28%] Built target _ur_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RobotStateRTMsg
[ 28%] Built target _ur_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_IOStates
[ 28%] Built target _ur_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_MasterboardDataMsg
[ 28%] Built target _ur_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Digital
[ 28%] Built target _ur_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SetPayload
[ 28%] Built target _ur_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Analog
[ 28%] Built target ur_driver_gencfg
[ 29%] Built target moveit_version
[ 29%] Built target moveit_exceptions
[ 29%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[ 29%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 29%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target moveit_profiler
[ 30%] Built target moveit_background_processing
[ 30%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target visualization_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target moveit_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target object_recognition_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target shape_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target _catkin_empty_exported_target
[ 30%] Built target octomap_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target tf_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 30%] Built target moveit_ros_planning_gencfg
[ 30%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 30%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 30%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 30%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 31%] Built target moveit_planners_ompl_gencfg
[ 31%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_eus
[ 31%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_py
[ 32%] Built target ur3_kin
[ 32%] Built target ur10_kin
[ 32%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 32%] Built target moveit_ros_manipulation_gencfg
[ 32%] Built target ur5_kin
[ 34%] Built target compliant_control
[ 35%] Automatic moc for target moveit_rviz_plugin_render_tools
[ 35%] Automatic moc for target moveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin
[ 35%] Automatic moc for target moveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin_core
[ 35%] Automatic moc for target moveit_planning_scene_rviz_plugin
[ 35%] Automatic moc for target moveit_planning_scene_rviz_plugin_core
[ 35%] Automatic moc for target moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core
[ 36%] Automatic moc for target moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin
[ 36%] Automatic moc for target moveit_trajectory_rviz_plugin_core
[ 36%] Built target moveit_rviz_plugin_render_tools_automoc
[ 36%] Built target moveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin_core_automoc
[ 36%] Built target moveit_planning_scene_rviz_plugin_automoc
[ 36%] Built target moveit_robot_state_rviz_plugin_automoc
[ 36%] Built target moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_core_automoc
[ 36%] Built target moveit_motion_planning_rviz_plugin_automoc
[ 36%] Built target moveit_trajectory_rviz_plugin_core_automoc
[ 36%] Built target moveit_planning_scene_rviz_plugin_core_automoc
[ 36%] Automatic moc for target moveit_setup_assistant_tools
[ 36%] Automatic moc for target moveit_setup_assistant_updater
[ 36%] Automatic moc for target moveit_trajectory_rviz_plugin
[ 36%] Automatic moc for target moveit_setup_assistant_widgets
[ 36%] Automatic moc for target moveit_setup_assistant
[ 38%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 39%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 41%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 43%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 45%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 47%] Built target ur_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 48%] Built target ur_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 50%] Built target ur_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 51%] Built target ur_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 52%] Built target ur_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 52%] Built target moveit_kinematics_base
[ 52%] Built target moveit_transforms
[ 52%] Built target moveit_setup_assistant_updater_automoc
[ 52%] Built target moveit_setup_assistant_tools_automoc
[ 52%] Built target moveit_trajectory_rviz_plugin_automoc
[ 52%] Built target moveit_setup_assistant_widgets_automoc
[ 52%] Built target ur_msgs_generate_messages
[ 52%] Built target pr2_msgs_generate_messages
[ 52%] Built target moveit_setup_assistant_automoc
[ 53%] Built target moveit_distance_field
[ 54%] Built target moveit_robot_model
[ 55%] Built target moveit_robot_state
[ 57%] Built target moveit_robot_trajectory
[ 57%] Built target moveit_kinematics_metrics
[ 57%] Built target moveit_dynamics_solver
[ 58%] Built target moveit_collision_detection
[ 58%] Built target moveit_trajectory_processing
[ 58%] Built target moveit_planning_interface
[ 59%] Built target moveit_collision_detection_fcl
[ 59%] Built target moveit_kinematic_constraints
[ 60%] Built target moveit_planning_scene
[ 60%] Built target moveit_planning_request_adapter
[ 61%] Built target moveit_constraint_samplers
[ 61%] Built target moveit_controller_manager_example
[ 61%] Built target moveit_ros_control_interface_plugin
[ 62%] Built target moveit_simple_controller_manager
[ 62%] Built target moveit_ros_control_interface_trajectory_plugin
[ 63%] Built target moveit_point_containment_filter
[ 63%] Built target moveit_semantic_world
[ 64%] Built target moveit_occupancy_map_monitor
[ 64%] Built target moveit_collision_distance_field
[ 64%] Built target moveit_lazy_free_space_updater
[ 64%] Built target moveit_occupancy_map_server
[ 64%] Built target moveit_pointcloud_octomap_updater_core
[ 64%] Built target collision_detector_hybrid_plugin
[ 65%] Built target moveit_rdf_loader
[ 65%] Built target moveit_pointcloud_octomap_updater
[ 65%] Built target moveit_planning_pipeline
[ 67%] Built target moveit_collision_plugin_loader
[ 67%] Built target moveit_constraint_sampler_manager_loader
[ 68%] Built target moveit_list_request_adapter_plugins
[ 68%] Built target moveit_kinematics_plugin_loader
[ 69%] Built target chomp_motion_planner
[ 70%] Built target moveit_default_planning_request_adapter_plugins
[ 70%] Built target moveit_robot_model_loader
[ 70%] Built target moveit_planners_chomp
[ 70%] Built target moveit_kinematics_speed_and_validity_evaluator
[ 71%] Built target moveit_evaluate_state_operations_speed
[ 71%] Built target moveit_print_planning_model_info
[ 71%] Built target moveit_planning_scene_monitor
[ 71%] Built target chomp_planner_plugin
[ 71%] Built target moveit_display_random_state
[ 71%] Built target demo_scene
[ 71%] Built target moveit_visualize_robot_collision_volume
[ 71%] Built target moveit_evaluate_collision_checking_speed
[ 71%] Built target moveit_trajectory_execution_manager
[ 71%] Built target moveit_publish_scene_from_text
[ 71%] Built target test_controller_manager_plugin
[ 72%] Built target test_controller_manager
[ 72%] Built target moveit_plan_execution
[ 72%] Linking CXX shared library /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_fake_controller_manager.so
[ 73%] Linking CXX shared library /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_srv_kinematics_plugin.so
[ 73%] Linking CXX shared library /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_cached_ik_kinematics_base.so
[ 74%] Linking CXX executable /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/moveit_kinematics/measure_ik_call_cost
[ 74%] Linking CXX shared library /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.so
[ 74%] Linking CXX shared library /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_lma_kinematics_plugin.so
[ 74%] Linking CXX shared library /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_move_group_capabilities_base.so
/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_plan_execution.so.0.9.11: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_plan_execution.so.0.9.11: file notmoveit/moveit_kinematics/srv_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_srv_kinematics_plugin.dir/build.make:277: recipe for target '/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_srv_kinematics_plugin.so.0.9.11' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_srv_kinematics_plugin.so.0.9.11] Error 1
 recognized:CMakeFiles/Makefile2:12977: recipe for target 'moveit/moveit_kinematics/srv_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_srv_kinematics_plugin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [moveit/moveit_kinematics/srv_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_srv_kinematics_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_plan_execution.so.0.9.11: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
moveit/moveit_plugins/moveit_fake_controller_manager/CMakeFiles/moveit_fake_controller_manager.dir/build.make:303: recipe for target '/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_fake_controller_manager.so.0.9.11' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_fake_controller_manager.so.0.9.11] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:12686: recipe for target 'moveit/moveit_plugins/moveit_fake_controller_manager/CMakeFiles/moveit_fake_controller_manager.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [moveit/moveit_plugins/moveit_fake_controller_manager/CMakeFiles/moveit_fake_controller_manager.dir/all] Error 2
moveit/moveit_kinematics/cached_ik_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_cached_ik_kinematics_base.dir/build.make:278: recipe for target '/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_cached_ik_kinematics_base.so.0.9.11' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_cached_ik_kinematics_base.so.0.9.11] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:13443: recipe for target 'moveit/moveit_kinematics/cached_ik_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_cached_ik_kinematics_base.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [moveit/moveit_kinematics/cached_ik_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_cached_ik_kinematics_base.dir/all] Error 2
/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_plan_execution.so.0.9.11: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
moveit/moveit_kinematics/cached_ik_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/measure_ik_call_cost.dir/build.make:278: recipe for target '/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/moveit_kinematics/measure_ik_call_cost' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/moveit_kinematics/measure_ik_call_cost] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:13304: recipe for target 'moveit/moveit_kinematics/cached_ik_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/measure_ik_call_cost.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [moveit/moveit_kinematics/cached_ik_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/measure_ik_call_cost.dir/all] Error 2
/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_plan_execution.so.0.9.11: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_plan_execution.so.0.9.11: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
moveit/moveit_kinematics/lma_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_lma_kinematics_plugin.dir/build.make:329: recipe for target '/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_lma_kinematics_plugin.so.0.9.11' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_lma_kinematics_plugin.so.0.9.11] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:12890: recipe for target 'moveit/moveit_kinematics/lma_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_lma_kinematics_plugin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [moveit/moveit_kinematics/lma_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_lma_kinematics_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
moveit/moveit_kinematics/kdl_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.dir/build.make:329: recipe for target '/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.so.0.9.11' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.so.0.9.11] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:12803: recipe for target 'moveit/moveit_kinematics/kdl_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [moveit/moveit_kinematics/kdl_kinematics_plugin/CMakeFiles/moveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_plan_execution.so.0.9.11: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
moveit/moveit_ros/move_group/CMakeFiles/moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.dir/build.make:310: recipe for target '/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_move_group_capabilities_base.so.0.9.11' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_move_group_capabilities_base.so.0.9.11] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:14481: recipe for target 'moveit/moveit_ros/move_group/CMakeFiles/moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [moveit/moveit_ros/move_group/CMakeFiles/moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.dir/all] Error 2
[ 74%] Linking CXX shared library /home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_ompl_interface.so
/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_plan_execution.so.0.9.11: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
moveit/moveit_planners/ompl/ompl_interface/CMakeFiles/moveit_ompl_interface.dir/build.make:701: recipe for target '/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_ompl_interface.so.0.9.11' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/kashyap/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libmoveit_ompl_interface.so.0.9.11] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:13877: recipe for target 'moveit/moveit_planners/ompl/ompl_interface/CMakeFiles/moveit_ompl_interface.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [moveit/moveit_planners/ompl/ompl_interface/CMakeFiles/moveit_ompl_interface.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

As far as i remember, I have not done any changes in my code in the past 4-5 days and suddenly I have this error. Can anyone tell what is it that I am doing wrong here or if I am missing something here

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291762/invoking-%22make--j8--l8%22-failed-file-not-recognized:-file-truncated/) by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-05-21**:
Are you using CCache? I've seen this error caused by ccache before. You could try cleaning your workspace and starting the build over. It seems like you have an issue with a library file getting corrupted... perhaps caused by interrupting a compilation process?

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-05-21**:
I guess I did interrupt the last compiling process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the guidelines in https://askubuntu.com/questions/645544/make-all-error-2-install-gr-ieee802-11 and it was solved

---

Originally posted by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) with karma: 46 on 2018-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-21**:
Which 'guidelines' are you referring to exactly? I checked that Q&A and it details how to build certain parts of `gnuradio`. I'm not entirely sure how that applies to your situation.

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-05-21**:
sudo apt-get install swig
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install cmake-data
sudo apt-get install liblog4cpp5-dev
sudo apt-get install libitpp-dev
sudo apt-get install libcppunit-dev
sudo apt-get install gnuradio-dev

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-21**:
This makes no sense to me at all ..

**Comment by [Kashyap.m94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33183/kashyap.m94/) on 2018-05-21**:
But could you explain why did I receive the error? Last time I was working on it, it was working. But today it started displaying this error. Any idea why is that? And if the above method is wrong, could you guide me through the correct way?